# Textview text size should be editText text size and displayed in listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textview, android-edittext

hello I'm new to Stackoverflow and also new to Andriod Studio.

As a first project, I would like to program a notes app.

My problem:

The editText text is saved as a txt file and displayed in a listview with the simple_list_item_1, but if I change the font size of the editText while the app is running and then display all notes, the text size of the listview item does not change.

My question:

how do you get the editText text font size to be displayed in the listview if I change the font size of the editText during the runtime of the app?

Comment: Hello! Could you post the code related to the problem so we could have a better idea of what you tried? Thanks.

Comment: @AntoineDelia He is asking how to hot reload application without reinstalling application. Something like flutter.

Comment: Are you changing system text size?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to change editText font size on running application but it's a compilation time action. So if you want to change font size and display it then you need to compile your project again with the new font size parameter. It will not be available on runtime if you write Java/Kotlin languages.
But it is available in Dart (on Flutter).

Answer (score 0):

You want the listview items to have the same font size as the editText has.

Please check the answer of this link it gives you the answer how to change the font size of the listview items:

[how to change text size of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456393/how-to-change-text-size-of-listview/20456446)

Further more if you want you can add some +/- buttons in the layout and change the size of the textview when pressing on them (increment/decrement).

Comment: thank you but,no I would like to transmit a separate text size for each new elment in the listview via the ediitext size